# Why I can't pass a parameter from cron to shell script

Tags: debian, shell, cron

With this cron script I am trying to get Rsync to work

```
*/1 * *    * * /root/backup.sh  `date +today/\%M`
```

And a shell script as the one below

```
#!/bin/bash -x
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
REMOTE="REMOTEADDRESS"
RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync
```

Comment: This works

```
$RSYNC -aqz --exclude-from '/home/root/backups/backup-exclude.txt' /var/www/html $REMOTE:backups/
```

Comment: This fails

```
$RSYNC -aqz  --exclude-from '/home/root/backups/backup-exclude.txt' /var/www/html $REMOTE:$1/
```

I am unable to understand why the passed parameter does not get passed correctly to the script. In the log everything looks as it should.

UPDATE
The reason for the cron to pass the parameter and not have it in the script is to have a backup schedule that allows to have :
- a backup each hour overwritten each day
- a backup each day overwritten each month 
- a persistent Backup each month

The error when passing the parameter is that RSync can not mkdir on the remote server. It can with any static line. The log shows the correct directory passed when using the current cron.

Comment: What is the error message of the failed rsync command?

Comment: Not really related, but why do you set the path _and_ use an absolute path to `rsync`?

Comment: The error from rsync is that I can't mkdir on the remote server. It can with the static command. I have been testing how to create a backup schedule where it backups every hour overwriting each day and then backing up each day overwriting each month and lastly have a persistent Backup each month. So I can't hardcode the path because it needs to vary with 3 cron scripts for the hour, day and month.

Comment: So it's a permission problem unrelated to cron.

Comment: How can it be that? The cron runs it perfectly with the static line? So why should the permission be different run it with a parameter?

Comment: Does `rsync` have to _create a new directory_ on the server when you run with the static argument? What happens if you change `backups/` to `today-test/44-test` in the static command?

Comment: @Kusalananda rsync creates a new directory on the server with the static command. I have removed the directory each time to ensure the same environment. With your test the directory and sub-directory is created.

Comment: @Scorekaj22 Well, that makes it interesting. You're not doing something like executing the two variants of the job as two different users?

Comment: @Kusalananda i am executing it in the same script run from the cron every time. So it is with same permissions and same user. That is why it confuses me a lot.

Comment: I just noticed that your script contains `REMOTE"REMOTEADDRESS"` with no equal sign...

Comment: @Kusalananda editing mistake from deleting the address. Sorry. It has been corrected now

Comment: Add `echo $RSYNC -aqz  --exclude-from '/home/root/backups/backup-exclude.txt' /var/www/html $REMOTE:$1/ > /tmp/cron-rsync` to the script and see what the actual command is when it runs. Just `printf '%s\n' "$1"` would probably do too.

Comment: @MichaelHomer i am running #!bin/sh -x and outputting to mail. The cron commands output there is today/09 for the var $1 at the nineth minute in the hour. i will test your printf tomorrow too.

Comment: @MichaelHomer This is the output `+ REMOTE="REMOTEADDRESS"
 + RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync`
 `+ /usr/bin/rsync -aqz --exclude-from /home/root/backups/backup-exclude.txt  /var/www/html REMOTE:today/08`
`rsync: mkdir "/volume2/homes/admin/today/08" failed: No such file or directory (2)`
`rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(615) [Receiver=3.0.9]`
`rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (163 bytes received so far) [sender]`

And your printf shows `+ printf %s\n today/08`
`today/08`

Comment: Then the problem is entirely with rsync and not with the script, parameters, cron or shell. You've got a clear error report: *rsync error: error in file IO (code 11)* of what went wrong.

Comment: Solution: make sure that the directory `/volume2/homes/admin/today/08` has been created in the target system before calling rsync for that directory.

Comment: @Isaac it might be a workaround that can be used. But the problem does not seem to be with rsync. When I set the path statically without a variable passed from cron it creates the directory. As soon as the path is created with a  variable passed it fails. Even with the same path as given from cron. I will test the workaround and see if it is able to create subdirectories automatically.

Comment: Do you mean to say that if the remote only has a directory with `/volume2/homes/admin/` **without any subdirectories** the command `rsync -aqz /var/www/html REMOTE:today/08` will run correctly (and without errors)?.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be `rsync -aqz /var/www/html REMOTE:/path/to/today/08` ??

Comment: @Isaac The root directory of the user meaning ~/ is the base directory after the REMOTE:. If I wrote REMOTE:PATH/TO/DIRECTORY/RANDOMDIRNAME it will create it but as soon as I use a passed variable with any path rsync fails. I can try to set a specific path starting with ~/ instead to see how that goes. I will test and return

Comment: @Scorekaj22 You missed a leading `/` :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that the directory where you are trying to copy to (the `dest/dir`) exists in the remote computer:

```
rsync -aqz ./ user@host:dest/dir
```

At minimum, all the directories (except the last one) should already exist.
That is the same behavior as `mkdir`: mkdir will only create the last directory (by default, the `-p` option can change that). 
That is: `rsync` will fail unless `/home/user/dest/dir` exists on the remote computer.

That is with **relative** directories.

The same also happens with **absolute** directories (ones that start with an `/`):

```
rsync -aqz ./ user@host:/home/user/dest/dir
```

The exact same rule but the directory is not **assumed** to be at the user home directory but could be anywhere (the user must have permissions to write to it, of course).

---

In additional testing I found that if `rsync` is going to use a directory like:

```
newdir/testdir
```

At least the directory newdir must exist. That is exactly the same as mkdir does. A `mkdir newdir/testdir` will fail if there is no `newdir` dir.

I tested it with the same script as you report:

- using with a fixed dir,
- a given dir on a parameter,
- a given dir on the script `$1` parameter
- all the above repeated with and without cron.

In all cases, missing the initial directory of a **two parts** directory gets rsync to fail.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer - I don't know how I succeeded in other tests. I must have somehow not deleted the directory. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, glad that you found a good solution. … I must make a note that you should quote `$REMOTE:$1/` as `"$REMOTE:$1/"` to avoid any **future** problems if the path could (at some future time) have spaces (any space or tab). :-)